crear un campo calculado en phpmyadmin 5 mediante la interfaz
Creo que se puede hacer modificando un campo desde el apartado estructura. Dentro del campo, en el apartado de virtualidad escojo "virtual" y me pide una expresión, no he encontrado información de como escribirla y lo que pruebo es campo1 / campo2 (quiero que en ese campo se guarde la división entre otros dos campos) le doy a guardar, no da error pero al darle a modificar el campo la opción virtualidad está vacía.. creo que se hace así y que el fallo está en la expresión, pero no encontré nada sobre el apartado virtualidad.
Gracias de antemano.

MÉTODO RÁPIDO -> En phpMyAdmin selecciona la tabla donde vas a crear el campo calculado, luego abres la pestaña SQL y crear el campo con la siguiente sentencia:
ALTER TABLE `tu_tabla_que_vas_a_modificar`
ADD COLUMN `campo_virtual` DECIMAL(10, 2) AS (IF(`campo2` = 0 OR `campo2` IS NULL, NULL, `campo1` / `campo2`)) VIRTUAL;

IMPORTANTE: Respeta las comillas invertidas, por otro lado, te puse en el código un seguro para así evitar la división por cero y que te de error.
Estos campos yo los usos para tener el valor a la mano de inventario de productos contra el precio del mercado.
METODO PASO A PASO -> Agrega como siempre en phpmyadmin una nueva columna
1.- Le pones el Nombre del campo: campo_virtual
2.- El Tipo: DECIMAL (o cualquier otro tipo adecuado)
3.- La Longitud/Valores: 10,2 (o según tus necesidades)
4.- En el campo Virtualidad: Selecciona VIRTUAL
 

Cuando seleccionas VIRTUAL te abre un campo llamado Expresión:
y es allí donde colocas:
`campo1` / `campo2` 

Si quieres ponerle el seguro de la division por cero en la expresion en phpmyadmin es asi:
if(((`campo2` = 0) or (`campo2` is null)),0,(`campo1` / `campo2`))

Recuerda respetar las comillas invertidas.
